# How to show error in View if the Controller fails ? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

On the **server-side** I have a transaction which returns a *JsonResult*:

```
public JsonResult DoStuff(Guid id, string userInputText)
{
     var product = _repository.Product(id); //busines logic

     //Only a specific product must have userInputText <= 10 characters. 
     //Other products may have as many characters as the user wants.
     if(product == Enum.SpecificProduct && userInputText.Count() > 10)
     {
          //The user input text comes from the View...
          //If it has more then 10 characters, need to send the errorMessage to the View.
          return Json(new { success = false, errorMessage = "error message" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }

     //Otherwise, do stuff on the product... 

     //and return success at the end.
     return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

On the other hand, on the **client-side** I have this:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoStuff", ajaxOptions))
{
    <span>Enter the text:</span>
    @Html.TextArea("userInputText", new { onkeyup = "SyncContents(); return false;" })

    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    <!-- error message should be displayed here-->
}
```

This is the AjaxOptions:

```
var ajaxOptions= new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = "reload",
    OnFailure = "FailMessage"
};
```

If the entered text have more then 10 characters, when the "Add" button is pressed, the Controller is being executing the code on the **server-side** and fails, how can I get the errorMessage from there and use it here, in the View, to inform the user ?

I tried to alert a message:

```
<script>
    function FailMessage() {
        alert("Fail Post");
    }
</script>
```

But no pop-up "Fail post" appears.

Best regards.

Comment: I am not sure how your ajaxOptions is connected with saveOptions in the code above. maybe change your ajaxOptions to new Ajaxoptions {     OnSuccess = "reload", OnFailure = "FailMessage" }, and remember to add a "," after "reload"

Comment: Really sorry for those mistakes, I've just edited my question. saveOptions is ajaxOption actually, I was coping the wrong name. Thank you.

Comment: So, the user can only type in up to 10 letters in the text-area.. if the user types in 11 or greater characters.. then you want an error message?

Comment: @T_Roy yes, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you are checking that on the server side?  That can be done with client-side validation

Comment: Okay, now that I'm a little more clear.. I would assume your error isn't being shown because the response code is in the 200 range.. you could throw an exception to get it in the 500 range.

Comment: @T_Roy Thank you for your time, throwing an exception is working.

Comment: You're welcome!  Would you like me to post that as an answer or are you using the answer below?

Comment: No its OK @T_Roy, don't waste your time anymore because I already used the one below after throwing an exception as you said, and I saw that was indeed the problem. Thank you again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the Ajax helper thinks all your responses are successful. Your controller action is returning HTTP 200 so there isn't a problem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions.OnFailure

**AjaxOptions.OnFailure Property**

> This function is called if the response status is not in the 200 range.

So you'll need to use the success handler and explicitly check the JSON `success` parameter.

Or have your action change the HttpStatusCode for the response.

```
if (notValid)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 400;  // Bad Request
    return Json(new { success = false, errorMessage = "error message" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But for a validation error here I'd just check the for an error in the success handler.

And yes, you should validate on the client and on the server.